# How in LabVIEW can I create an output from a flow meter(4-20mA to kg/s) when the min/max calculations depend on pressure

Tags: labview, pressure

[Steam flow/pressure, calculations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnvXF.jpg)
I have a small Labview project recording the flow of steam at different pressures. I have a pressure sensor pre-flowmeter so have the system pressure at hand.
I am seeking a way of getting the output from the flow meter (of which the range changes with pressure). How can I mathematically include this to get an accurate reading from 1 to 4 bar. The flow meters calculations change at 1,2,4,6 bar.
Many thanks
Ian

Comment: Maybe posting snapshots and what you have done so far would help everyone get further details to help you out.

Comment: It sounds as if you just need to select a different formula, or different coefficients in a formula, based on the pressure value, but it's hard to answer this without seeing more detail. Can you either edit this in to your post, or link to some documentation for the flow meter which explains this?

Answer (score 0):

A case structure should solve this issue.  Depending on the input pressure in bar, you can adjust the calculation output.  It may take some testing to see how the overlaps are handled, they could introduce discontinuities in the outputs.

Comment: Hi @Good@Neo@nekomatic, and thanks for your input, I've included a shot of the block diagram which explains what I am trying to do. I cannot connect the steam code to the front panel indicator so the output goes direct to the DAX . This works on the basis of increase pressure moving to the correct line of equation with an indicator o showing which line is live, but its messy with multiple moving parameters. I'm sure there must be an easier way of doing this, but I can't find it.

Comment: @IanKemp I can't see a screenshot. Have you edited it into your question?

Comment: Sorry, I had thought included the link, its there now. Thanks